# Acessar horas e minutos com Angular Timer

Tags: angularjs

Quero pegar os dados de horas e minutos do Angular Timer e jogar em uma variável para salvar no banco, como faço?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interrompa o Timer com um broadcast:

```
$scope.$broadcast('timer-stop');
```

Ao mesmo tempo, monitore o evento `timer-stopped`, e capture o objeto contendo o estado do timer:

```
$scope.$on('timer-stopped', function (event, data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

O objeto conterá as seguintes propriedades:

> days
>   **hours**
>   millis
>   **minutes**
>   seconds
>   timeoutId

Comment: Deu certo, mas usando o ng-click tenho que executar duas vezes para exibir no console e atribuir em outra variável. Pode ser algum problema com o ng-click ou assincronismo? Obrigado.